# How to display all username and email objects from main User class into UITableView in parse.com?

Tags: xcode, parse-platform

assume that i want to have a UITableView as an **admin** for my app, i want to see every registered user from my application instead of seeing them in the Parse.com

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing that each row in the User table has ACL column with allowed "read" from public access (i'm not sure but it should also works with default empty field ACL column), then you should simply do this:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
query.skip = 0;
query.limit = 1000;
// put all your necessary filter on this query obj   

// perform query in background if needed
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

// fill datasource table and reload data

}];
```

Keep in mind that parse allow to retrieve 1000 rows maximum for query ( so use the skip and limit for load users with lazy loading pattern )

Hope it helps